# Intent filters not working to open custom app

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to get a URL to open up a custom application that I've written but the intent filters don't seem to be working. I've looked at a dozen or so threads in SO that seem to offer the "solution" but for me it's no good.

I need to have the action from a QR code scan open up my app. Therefore, I'm not inside any browser clicking any links. I'm simply opening my QR scanner, scanning a QR code, and wanting that to fire up my app instead of opening up the default Web browser. The default action for the QR Scanner is to open up the URI in the web browser.

The manifest.xml is this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="tinysb.com" android:path="/ecard/" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

My QR code points to http://tinysb.com/ecard/ so I'm looking for something to start up my app instead of the browser if that link is encountered by any application. Currently, the browser starts up and I'm not even given the option of what to do once I scan the QR code. For now, I'm not passing anything from the Web server, so I just need it to start up my app without passing anything into it.

Since this is all initiated from the QR scanner, there's no activity I can code to intercept the URI.

Many posts have said that setting up the android:scheme per above should do the trick, but it's not working for me at all.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is what I'm asking not possible or did I phrase the question poorly?

Comment: Does your code work if you click a link in the browser?
Scanning a QR code with a YouTube URL in it prompts me to open the YouTube app - so this is possible.

Answer (score 3):

The problem might be the QR Code scanner you are using. An application can appoint an Application to open the url instead of letting the android intent chooser handle it. Do you have several browser installed and are you prompted to choose one of them?

The following intent filter is working for me:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
  <data android:host="getamen.com" android:scheme="http" android:pathPrefix="/topics"/>
</intent-filter>
```

You could try using android:pathPrefix="/ecard" or adding the BROWSABLE category.